# Sum of input fields into #total readonly field

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery function on `keyup` which calculates number of boys enrollments in different classes (using fields) and puts the sum in total boys enrollment field.

```
$("#Asc201516EleClassEceBoysEnrollment").keyup(function(){
            var sum = 0;

            ece    = +$("#Asc201516EleClassEceBoysEnrollment").val();               
            katchi = +$("#Asc201516EleClassKatchiBoysEnrollment").val();
            one    = +$("#Asc201516EleClassEceOneEnrollment").val();
            two    = +$("#Asc201516EleClassEceTwoEnrollment").val();
            three  = +$("#Asc201516EleClassThreeBoysEnrollment").val();
            four   = +$("#Asc201516EleClassFourBoysEnrollment").val();
            five   = +$("#Asc201516EleClassFiveBoysEnrollment").val();
            six    = +$("#Asc201516EleClassSixBoysEnrollment").val();
            seven  = +$("#Asc201516EleClassSevenBoysEnrollment").val();
            eight  = +$("#Asc201516EleClassEightBoysEnrollment").val();
            nine   = +$("#Asc201516EleClassNineBoysEnrollment").val();
            ten    = +$("#Asc201516EleClassTenBoysEnrollment").val();

            sum =  sum + parseInt(ece+katchi+one+two+three+four+five+six+seven+eight+nine+ten);             
            console.log(sum);

            $("#Asc201516EleTotalBoysEnrollment").val(sum);

        });
```

I get `NaN` in `#Asc201516EleTotalBoysEnrollment` input field. What could be the issue? Same function is working fine for other group (teachers total) of fields on the same page.

Comment: One of the variables is not a number probably, so you will get a Not A Number error.

Comment: One of the values returned is Not A Number, you have to check each one to figure out which one it is, we can't do it for you

Comment: @adeneo Thanks bro, you were right. 
I had one    = +$("#Asc201516EleClassEceOneEnrollment").val();
and two    = +$("#Asc201516EleClassEceTwoEnrollment").val(); 

instead of Asc201516EleClassOneBoysEnrollment and Asc201516EleClassTwoBoysEnrollment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to keep the individual counts in their global variables, as shown in your example (did you declare these variables anywhere with `var ...`?!?) then you could instead do the whole thing with this slighty shorter function:

```
$("#Asc201516EleClassEceBoysEnrollment").keyup(function(){
  var sum=0
  ['ece','katchi','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten'].forEach(function(el){
      sum += ~~$("#Asc201516EleClass"+el+"BoysEnrollment").val();
  })
  console.log(sum);
  $("#Asc201516EleTotalBoysEnrollment").val(sum);
});
```

In JavaScript `~` is the bitwise `NOT`-Operator. Applying it twice will turn *any* string into an integer value and can therefore be seen as the "more tolerant brother" of the standard `parseInt()` function. `NaN` will appear as `0` and `float` values will be truncated.

( Applying the `+` operator on each string returned by `.val()`, as you did it, will also try to convert  a string into an integer, but if the string contains any characters not compatible with an integer format the result will be `NaN` and ultimately spoil your summation. )